# Tableau - Calculating and presenting epidemiologic Incidence and Incidence Rate/10,000

Tags: tableau-api, constants, rate

I'm trying to calculate the Incidence (daily), the Cumulative Incidence (over a prolonged time period), the Incidence Rate /10,000 (daily) and the Cumulative Incidence Rate/10,000 (over a prolonged time period) of an infectious disease.  This is for the entire US, a variable number of States (referred to later as "i"), and a variable number of Counties in those specified States (referred to later as "j").  ("Incidence" is the number of cases in a given period of time - in this case a day.)

The data is in a table with columns of 'Date', 'Incidence', 'Cumulative Incidence', 'Incidence/10,000', 'Cumulative Incidence/10,000'.  The population for each State and County is taken from a look-up table from the Census Bureau organized by 'State', 'County', 'Population' (done programmatically with a JOIN on 'State' and 'County').

For a given measure (say, Incidence Rate /10,000), the calculation is `('Incidence'/'Population') * 10,000`.

Doing the Incidence and Cumulative Incidence in Tableau is straightforward - using Rows of SUM('Incidence') vs Columns of 'Date' and Rows of SUM('Cumulative Incidence') vs Columns of 'Date'.

Doing the 'Incidence Rate/1,000' and 'Cumulative Incidence Rate/10,000' is not so obvious.  For the US, SUM('Cumulative Incidence') trends ever upward as expected; SUM('Cumulative Incidence Rate/10,000' rises to a certain degree, and then levels off waving around with ups and downs; and SUM('Population') rises asymptotically until it reaches "almost" the toal population of the US.  What I think I am seeing is that the Incidence being measured started from a small area, and has kept on growing until almost (but not all, States and Counties are involved (there are rare Counties not involved, but all States are).  I assume the SUM('Population') is actually a Σij of 'Population' over i = State and j = County on any given day and that Σij of 'Cumulative Incidence Rate/10,000' on a given day.  What it is not is a  Σij of 'Population' over i = State and j = County over all days (AKA a Constant) that is available from the look-up table. and is date independent.

Any thoughts? (I'm sure there is a simple answer, but new to this) .  Using Tableau Desktop 2020.1.3

My thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need an aggregate calculated field or a level of detail (LOD) calculated field.

Try putting the aggregation functions into the calculation, such as `SUM([Incidence]) / SUM([Population])` This calculation computes the sums first, and then divides them at the end, instead of computing a ratio for each record and then summing the ratios. That’s often necessary when working with ratios.

Moreover, I expect your Population values don’t change each day, so if you simply aggregate them using Sum() as above, you would inflate the denominator. In that case, you need to first compute the population at a different level of detail using an LOD calculation. An example formula in that case would be something like

`SUM([Incidence]) / { FIXED [State], [County] : MAX([Population])}`

It’s hard to tell the correct formula to recommend without some sample data, but it’s likely something similar to the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Alex - So many thanks!!!!

You got me 90% of the way there.  Your formula threw an error, complaining that `SUM([Incidence]` is Aggregated, and `{FIXED [State], [County] : MAX([Population])}` is not.  This fix was to turn this into `MAX({FIXED [State], [County] : MAX([Population])})` which is Aggregated (it made no difference whether one uses `MAX()`, `MIN()`, or `AVG()`, since you suggested `MAX([Population]` in the first place, I used that).  Given that the numbers are small, in this case I chose to multiply by 10,000 to give an Incidence Rate/10,000 people (this is common in epidemiology to compare Incidence amongst varying population sizes to “normalize” Relative Risk).  In the end the formula has become:

`(SUM([Incidence]) * 10000) / MAX({FIXED [State], [County] : MAX([Population])})`

This corresponds to the tabular data calculated as `([Incidence] * 10000) / [Population]` for each State and County.